# Silverlight Out of Browser (OOB) app crashing only on OS X

Tags: silverlight, macos

We have a Silverlight application that runs OOB (out of browser) so the user can install it.  When it's running OOB we display a button that calls Application.Current.MainWindow.Close() so that the user can exit the application.  This works perfectly fine on windows, but causes an error saying the application has quit unexpectedly on OS X.  Anyone have any ideas why this might be?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem.  This is apparently a "protected" action and must be done directly in response to a user action.  It cannot be scheduled to happen later (we were playing an animation on the button click and then after a timer expired trying to close the window; we have to just close the window).

An exception was actually thrown on the windows version, it just never displayed any sort of message box.